# AutoCompleteTextView combine open results below (by setting dropDownHeight?) and wrap content

Tags: android, dropdown, autocompletetextview, android-wrap-content

I'm using autoCompleteTextViews and i need the results to open below the field and wrap the content.

My solution was to set dropDownHeight to a certain value that would guarantee i have enough room below.
On 2 Samsung devices a tried, this works great. The problem is on other devices I lose the wrap content behavior. So if, for example, I only get 1 result but i set the dropDownHeight to 200dp, I'm left with lots of empty space.
So ideally I would like a way to set a max dropDownHeight, while setting the dropDownHeight to wrap_content.
Alternatively, i can leave the dropDownHeight as wrap content if there's another way to force the results to open below the field.
thanks.